# Static in earphones when scrolling with mouse

Tags: audio, noise, computers

Why do I sometimes hear faint static in my headphones when I scroll with my mouse? I have noticed this on multiple(4) computers, with Windows 7 and 8. Does anybody else notice this? It happens when I have programs running that make noise, and when there are no programs running that generate sound, such as browsing a web page. Does anybody have an idea where this comes from? It doesn't bother me, because its so faint, but I am very curious.  I'm guessing that it is a hardware issue of some kind.

Comment: Try disabling the microphone boost and turning the mic down in the control panel. This question will be closed pretty quickly, it's not an EE question.

Comment: @bers On desktop computers many people *never* use a microphone. In fact, the lack of a microphone and camera might be considered a security feature.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I take everything back. Not only was I thinking about laptops (with built-in mics) and disregarded desktop computers; what's more, I disabled the mic device on my laptop (with built-in mic) and it actually solved the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "static" is noise coupled into the headphone driver circuit via its power supply. An action such as scrolling a window on a display causes a large burst of memory activity (a "block move" of the pixels involved, plus drawing the new material that is revealed), and if the decoupling is inadequate, this causes rapid sags in the voltages of the power supplies involved in this activity. If those same voltages are used to drive the headphone, or if there is sufficient coupling between voltages, and the headphone driver has poor power supply rejection, you'll hear this noise in the headphones.

Comment: In other words, someone skimped on your computer's audio design. Your computer is crap! I'm in the same boat haha :(

Comment: Thank you, that's very educational.  I asked this on SuperUser exchange, and nobody answered, but I was sure there was somebody here knowledgeable enough to answer my question.